# Send Outlook Task Via PHP

Tags: php, outlook

I've seen this question asked a couple of times on Stack, but I'm not seeing any actual answers here or anywhere on the web.

I'm trying to send an Outlook task via PHP. After a lot of false starts and incorrect/outdated information on the web, I have been able to get a Calendar invite sent, but I'm actually looking for the Task type from Outlook - unfortunately client request is specifically not for a Calendar type invite. I assume that the process is similar, but I have been unable to find the format for the message body to successfully send a Task. Could someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the library https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews to develop PHP-to-Exchange web applications. It will work with email, calendars, tasks, and more.

Keep in mind this will only work with a Microsoft Exchange Server; Outlook itself is an email client that can work with a variety of servers, but is targeted towards Exchange environments.

My general experience regarding working with PHP and Exchange is that is a significant learning curve, and much of it is dependent upon the version of Exchange you are running as well as the ever-changing versions of the PHP libraries developed for it.

Comment: I've beat my head against this library for a while now and still don't even have the classes loading correctly. Are you familiar with any resources for this particular library beyond the author's rather sparse notes?